# return the innermost return statement in js

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a function, which calls another function and so on like

```
var fn1 = function() { return 'bar'; };
var fn2 = function() {
  return fn1;
};
var fn3 = function() {
  return fn2;
};
```

now this can keep on going.

Therefore I would like to recursively call a method, till I get a string/value i.e. the innermost return statement.

I tried like this:

```
function p (val){
var res = val;
while(typeof(res)=="function"){res = p()}
return res;
}
```

and calling it like p(fn2); but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing.

Comment: Calling `p()` will not change anything. You don't give it any value, nor do you use what it returns. It either passes and has no effect, or at most it errors. Don't think it can error here, so it just does nothing.

Comment: Also, why are you missing `while` and recursion? You should only need one in this case.

Comment: Yes got my mistake. Thanks

Comment: There's always something like this: `const p = (val) => typeof val == 'function' ? p (val ()) : val`

Answer (score 2):

You need to reassign the `res` (or `val`) inside the loop, then return it (don't return the `p`) at the end:

```js
var fn1 = function() {
  return 'bar';
};
var fn2 = function() {
  return fn1;
};
var fn3 = function() {
  return fn2;
};



function p(val) {
  while (typeof val === "function") {
    val = val();
  }
  return val;
}

console.log(p(fn3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var fn1 = function() {
  return 'bar';
};
var fn2 = function() {
  return fn1;
};
var fn3 = function() {
  return fn2;
};    

function p(val) {
  if (typeof val === "function") {
    return p(val())
  }
  return val;
}

console.log(p(fn3));
```